# bokeh - plot overlaps on xaxis when output_backend = "webgl"

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm writing a data visualization app using bokeh (and bokeh.models API), and I found a strange behaviour : when using pan tool, plot is overlaping X-axis, but only if I set output_backend = "webgl" (and I need webgl to keep smooth user experience with the "large" dataset I planned to visualize)

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a bug ?

[image: plot overlaps x axis]

The code to generate this image is the following one :

```
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, DataRange1d, LinearAxis, Line
from bokeh.models import PanTool, ResetTool
from bokeh.plotting import show
import numpy as np

# generate data
x = [i for i in np.arange(0, 70, 0.1)]
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y = y))

# configure plot
plot = Plot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), plot_height=300, plot_width=400, output_backend="webgl")
x_axis = LinearAxis()
y_axis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(x_axis, "below")
plot.add_layout(y_axis, "left")
plot.add_tools(PanTool(), ResetTool())

# add Line to plot
glyph = Line(x="x", y="y", line_color="red")
glyphrenderer = plot.add_glyph(source, glyph)

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently known issues and bugs with webgl in current releases (circa `0.12.13`). Unfortunately the original maintainer of the webgl component no longer contributes to the project, so it will be an unknown amount of time before these get addressed. At best I can suggest to try  earlier versions, when things were working better.

That said, if the code above is indicative of your actual data size, then just turn webGL off, standard HTML canvas rendering works fine for anything that small.

Comment: Yes, turning off webgl is a good idea if the amount of data is not big (I need to check). Plus, I suppose that it is well working with datashader images. Thank for your answer, I wish to be good enough and have enough time to help improving bokeh...

Comment: @bigreddot, How do you select and older version and can you maybe let us know which version is the correct one for a lot of data? like is it 0.12.10 or older?

Comment: That depends on your setup. The most common package managers `conda` and `pip` both allow you to ask for a specific version when you install any package. Regarding Bokeh versions, I don't have any specific guidance to offer, you will just have to try your specific code and see if it works. However, subsequent to this answer there was a round of webgl work, so you might actually want to try the *newest* Bokeh version.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks for answering but it didn't help my specific case. I'm visualizing a tree with 900 nodes but it takes 16 seconds already to do that in Python using libraries like networkx, Pydot from Bokeh. So i thought i could speed it up a bit because i want to visualize a tree with 300k nodes :/ I tried multiple implementations of different visualizations like "Force-directed graph drawing" and "Twopi draws graphs" but the running time is still the same. Do you have an advice for me?

Comment: Not really, as one of the core developers, would say Bokeh is not a  great choice for large graphs, and probably never will be. Even with webgl there would still be significant overhead to support the interactive features that Bokeh prioritizes. You might have a look at DataShader to pre-render the graph.

Comment: @bigreddot can i contact you somehow to ask you more about that? If you don't mind of course

Comment: The mailing list is probably the best place for continued discussion https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh